# How To Trigger UserNotifications 2 Days Before Specific Date

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, usernotifications

How To Trigger UserNotifications 2 Days Before Specific Date

I Tried to UserNotification Before but I Know I base on time interval, but I don't know how can I trigger this notification base on date.. can someone help me please.. thanks.. :)

Comment: The doc says...  // Fire in 30 minutes (60 seconds times 30)
let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: (30*60), repeats: false)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out thanks for the help. El Tomato

```
func prepareNotification() {

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Eva Reminder"
    content.body = "2 Days Left Before Your Period Days."
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    var components = DateComponents()
    components.day = numberOfDaySelected - 2
    components.hour = 7
    components.minute = 0
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: components, repeats: true)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "eva.notification", content: content, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
}
```